# express detect get request

Tags: javascript, express, electron

I'm using electron to build an app which serves several image files in a webserver using express.

From another app built in Android I get files from the server and post files to it.

I have no problems detecting when the Android app is posting the files:

```
app.post('/fileupload', function(req, res) {
    alert("post");
    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        //console.log("Uploading: " + filename); 
        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/images/' + filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
            res.redirect('back');
        });
    });
});
```

But still have no success detecting when the Android app get the files from the server (it gets them, but I have no way to refresh my output screen when it does), I'm trying with this code:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  alert("get");
  next();
});
```

and this one too:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  alert("get");
  next();
});
```

I'm putting the files in a directory called images:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.use(express.static('images'));
app.listen(3000);
```

**EDIT**

If I open a browser with the same url Android is getting, it triggers the event and shows the alert. Why it doesn't trigger when Android opens the connection?, I don't know.
The Android code for the get request is:

```
 URL url = new URL(sURL);
 HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
 conection.setRequestMethod("GET");
 conection.connect();
 int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

 InputStream inputURL = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
```

Comment: use like console.log("test++++++++++++") instead alert() , to check if request made on server

Comment: same result with console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code, that is deprecated using my compile versión (23), express detects the get request.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
// Prepare a request object
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(sURL.substring(0, sURL.lastIndexOf("/")));
// Execute the request
HttpResponse response;
response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling API's then you should use res.send() using json

```
 app.post('/fileupload', function(req, res) {
        alert("post");
        var fstream;
        req.pipe(req.busboy);
        req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
            //console.log("Uploading: " + filename); 
            fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/images/' + filename);
            file.pipe(fstream);
            fstream.on('close', function () {

                 res.send({status:1,data:{}})  //check this response on android side and change/refresh screen on android side if needed 
                //res.redirect('back');

            });
        });
    });
```